# Editing ASPX in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64

I have recently upgraded from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2010 (and also moved from Windows XP 32 bit to Windows 7 64 bit).

Whenever I edit an ASPX file in my project VS2010 throws an exception:

```
"A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.dll
Additional information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."
```

I have edit and continue turned on and am targeting X86 (as 64 bit E&C doesn't work)

Is there a known issue for this or is it something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling VS 2010?

Comment: it's pretty much a brand new installation...